# error while executing batch file in windows OS

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

i have made a batch file in windows 7 OS. When i double click on that batch file it opens in notepad and it is not executing code of my batch file. What should i do now to run or execute batch file? Please help me. It is so much serious for me .

Comment: Did you save it as All Files when you created it?

Comment: yes i save it as .bat extension but it is not working.

Comment: Do you have [hide extensions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/865219) for known file types enabled under Folder options? Do a `dir` in the location of the .bat file and see if it shows as batchfile.bat.txt.

Comment: no it shows as batchfile.bat not batchfile.bat.txt

Comment: Make sure PATHEXT system variable has .bat in it. you can run from cmd echo %pathext%

Comment: is this the behavior for all batch files or just the one you created?

Comment: Yes, this behavior is same for all batch file on my system. before 2-3 months every batch file execute properly.but from 2-3 week it's creating this problem.

Comment: echo %pathext% shows .BAT extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK there are many things that could be wrong and many ways to fix it but i think the quickest way to fix it would be to rename you file to a .cmd instead of a .bat (they are just the same.)

Answer (score 0):

find that reg key and delete value data "notepad.exe"

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER \Software \Microsoft \Windows \CurrentVersion \ Explorer \FileExts \.bat \
```

it will work.